# m2doc for general document generation

Tags: eclipse, model, document, eclipse-emf, m2doc

I'm exploring the use of m2doc for government documentation generation: I'm a systems engineer in my organization and we're trying to automate the generation of yearly budget proposals using this software. A lot of people work on these documents and usually they introduce errors; for example, a certain value could change and is not updated in all the places where it appears in the document.

The final solution would include a model that I would design with the general structure of all the attributes that the document requires (entities, amounts, government programs, etc.); I would provide an expert with a Word template to include the elements to be integrated, in addition to all the legal text that the document must include; finally, there would be a tool for financial personnel to enter these elements as real data (something that would allow to maintain several versions of the data). In the end, we would generate versions of the document using m2doc. My idea is to gradually advance the solution, where a first version could be done manually (as a proof of concept), even using Eclipse as the main integration and generation tool.

I lack a broad experience with Eclipse, Java programming, et al, but I feel that I could develop a solution for what we need. In my opinion the [m2doc site](https://www.m2doc.org/) requires more information about the integration with the models and their data, which is the part where I am having problems now.

My current understanding is that there is this [Eclipse Modeling Framework](https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) (EMF) that provides a way to describe data models and that m2doc can use any model based on EMF (pure or one of its variants) as a basis for document generation. My problem is that, using a pure EMF model, I can't find a way to associate an instance of said model (like an XML serialized representation) to the document generation, only the model itself: in other words, when creating the generation configuration (.genconf file) it will tell m2doc (among other things) what is the model variable to use, which is an .ecore resource, but not an instance *with real data*, and I can't continue from there.

I hope someone can guide me on my problem or tell me where I can find a complete example that uses the technology: on the m2doc site there is no example project that I can download (or at least, I could not find it).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to content types. Your xml file is not recognized as a model by EMF. You need to create an [Ecore model from your xsd](https://www.davehofmann.de/generating-emf-models-from-xml-schema-definitions-xsds/). When all plugins are generated using the genmodel (EMF not M2Doc genconf) and installed in your environment (or by launching a runtime Eclipse), you should be able to load your xml file as an EMF model. M2Doc rely on EMF for model loading.